# jQuery scale/zoom on hover function

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I was wondering if someone could point me into the right direction.

I have created a scaling effect with CSS3 transition. Hover over the object and it transitions to a larger version.  This looks great and works awesome, but the problem is taht this effect won't work in IE, so I need to create a smooth version in jQuery.  I have found a tutorial that does exactly that but I don't like the jaggedy effect is gives when implementing it. Here is the link to the tutorial

[Jquery Hover State](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/)

so if anyone has a solution for me to get a smooth transition out of a jQuery function that will work in IE i will be very grreatful

here is a fiddle I create with the intended CSS3 transition. -

[CSS3 Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Diezel23/7perw/)

I would like to achieve the same smooth hover state with Jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have two propositions for You.

First using animate function:

```
$("a").hover(function()
{
  $(this).animate({"padding": "40px"}, "fast");
},
function()
{
   $(this).animate({"padding": "30px"}, "fast");
}
);
```

Second using element scaling:

```
$("a").hover(function()
{
  $(this).width($(this).width()+5);
  $(this).height($(this).height()+5);
},
function() 
{
    $(this).width($(this).width()-5);
    $(this).height($(this).height()-5);
}
);
```

Comment: No for some reason this is not working, where I'm usung it is a bit more complex. its li's with divs inside of the containing elements. the whole build is responsive so it works in peresentages.

I am using another of Shotankas great tutorials to create the smart columns

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/smart-columns-w-css-jquery/

these boxes then have to zoom using a z-index on the box.

I updated my fiddle for this to give you kinda a idea